# Best way of migrating Windows Phone 8.1 App to Universal 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, universal

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 App, and I want to convert it in Univesal 8.1 App.
So what I think to do is just to add Windows 8.1 Project to the WP 8.1 solution and a Shared project as well and than reference that shared project to both Windows and WP 8.1 project, but I want to know that going for that approach can really be considered as universal App?
When we create a Univeral 8.1 App by File->New Project from VS, I guess it's also doing almost similar thing, but I am not sure if there's any magic going under the hood.
Please suggest me correct way of converting my current WP 8.1 app to Universal 8.1 App.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right ,
1.just add windows 8.1 project from sol explorer to your existent one that is wp8.1 
2. then you will get 3 projects in your solution explorer
    a)Your existent wp8.1 app
    b)newly created windows 8.1 app
    c)Common project called shared project
3.Now you need to create view regarding windows 8.1 app and your back-end coding part like model and view-models you need to keep in shared project.
4.so now your UI is different for both but back-end C# coding thing is same for the both.